# How to easily read not simple English?

Tags: understanding, reading

I am an intermediate level English learner and I wish to be fluent in English in order to be able to easily read academic subjects, books, novels, and researches written in not simple English, so I need to know what I should do to reach that level.

#### Note

I don't have the opportunity to immerse myself in an English-speaking community.

Comment: Keep reading. Keep notes. Take an advanced grammar course. Learns lots of idioms.

Comment: Read. Read. Read. Try to read whole paragraphs without resorting to a dictionary and see if you can get the gist of what you're read. Then go and look up the vocabulary you don't know and reassess. Keep doing that, over and over. Eventually it will come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reading academic and technical studies it is probably more important to be intimately familiar with the subject matter than to have mastered the subtleties of English expression. When you are reading about topics you understand you will have a much stronger sense of what the author *ought* to mean, and the English will 'creep' into your unconscious mind without your noticing—you will be learning academic English the same way a native speaker learns it, by experience rather than application.

By the same token, I recommend reading English translations of works by writers from your own speech community whom you enjoy: it is much easier to read stories which deal with people and situations you know and with genre conventions you already understand.